# Is it correct to redirect the old site to the new domain and the further redirect for new URL capitalization?

Tags: seo, redirects, url, canonical-url

I am wondering whether this setup is correct.

I have a website running HTTP `domain1.example` and I redirect links to `domain2.example` using a 301 redirect. domain2 works fine but I decided to implement URL capitalization. Thinking that `domain2.example/abc` has inherited power from `domain1.example/abc` I can now use a canonical to specify the correct version `domain2.example/Abc`.

Is that assumption incorrect and I need another 301?

[Source](https://moz.com/blog/subdomains-vs-subfolders-rel-canonical-vs-301-how-to-structure-links-optimally-for-seo-whiteboard-friday):

> Hey, I want to maintain the branding or some unique aspect of
>   something that happens around othersite.com, and so I wish that I
>   could have visitors be able to still go to that page, but have search
>   engines know, hey this is actually just a copied version of this one,
>   and if you're going to rank one of these two, I'd prefer you to rank
>   this one.

Answer (score 1):

It is very common to wholesale redirect domains and then further redirect within the domain for moved pages, capitalization, or any number of other reasons.  It is typically done this way because of ease of implementation.   It is difficult to put all the fine grained redirect logic in place on every single possible alternate domain.  Almost no website does that.

A short chain of redirects is fine. Two redirects is no problem at all for search engines. I've only seen problems once you get to five or more sequential redirects.

What you want to avoid is a situation like:

`http://domain1.example/abc` → `http://www.domain1.example/abc` → `https://domain1.example/abc` → `http://domain2.example/abc` → `http://www.domain2.example/abc` → `https://www.domain2.example/abc` → `https://www.domain2.example/Abc`

Instead you want :

- `http://domain1.example/abc` → `https://www.domain2.example/abc` → `https://www.domain2.example/Abc`
- `https://domain1.example/abc` → `https://www.domain2.example/abc` → `https://www.domain2.example/Abc`
- `http://www.domain1.example/abc` → `https://www.domain2.example/abc` → `https://www.domain2.example/Abc`
- `https://www.domain1.example/abc` → `https://www.domain2.example/abc` → `https://www.domain2.example/Abc`
- `http://domain2.example/abc` → `https://www.domain2.example/abc` → `https://www.domain2.example/Abc`
- `https://domain2.example/abc` → `https://www.domain2.example/abc` → `https://www.domain2.example/Abc`
- `http://www.domain2.example/abc` → `https://www.domain2.example/abc` → `https://www.domain2.example/Abc`

So that regardless of what combination of alternate domain, `www`, or `http` is hit, the first redirect is to the canonical `https://www.domain2.example/` and then there could possibly be a second redirect to correct spelling.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a valid reason why you would like to implement 301s and generate a redirection chain. However, I would strongly suggest to avoid this approach.

You should use one redirect e.g. domain1.com/abc to domain2.com/Abc (capital) and that’s it. if feasible update your old links and avoid 301s.

A good webmaster will tend to minimise as much as possible the number of redirects users/bots “perceive”, for this reason I would also suggest that If you have external links pointing to domain2.com/abc do not implement 301 on those particular pages (pages with backlinks) in this case use canonical tags. This way you will let good webmasters know that their link pointing to your website are in good condition (they won’t receive reports from their website generating unnecessary 301s).

From the SEO point of view my last paragraph is actually a mediocre advise, keep in mind that Canonical tags are not meant to be treated as a 301s, they have a different purpose and use case in the webmaster world. To give you an example Canonicals are meant to be used in scenarios where results in a page are further arranged or filtered by parameters in the URL, e.g. ecommerce.

In short, avoid 301s as much as you can, and use canonical tags correctly.

Comment: A short chain of redirects is fine.  Two redirects is no problem at all for search engines.   I've only seen problems once you get to five or more sequential redirects.